# Use CSS to move images in text flow to right hand side

Tags: html, css

I have some basic markup along these lines:

```
<div class="page_content">
    <p>A paragraph of text.</p>
    <p>Another paragraph of text.</p>
    <img src="image.jpg" />
    <p>Some more text.</p> 
</div>
```

The paragraphs are constrained in size, i.e. `.page_content p{min-width:24em;max-width:36em}`. I'm aiming for a responsive layout.

At large browser widths I would like to move the images out of the main flow of text to achieve a layout along these lines (n.b. image in html above may not match position shown below!):

```
    ===== = Image

    --------
    --------
    --------

    -------- ======
    -------- ======
    -------- ======
    --------

    --------
    --------
    --------
```

If I `float:right` the images, they scoot out of the text, with their top edge in line with their 'parent' paragraph. However, they are aligned all the way over to the right hand side of the page. I don't seem to be able to find a way to keep them flush to the right hand side of the paragraph that they sit with.

I don't want to move the images out of the main page_content div, because at small screen widths I'm looking to have the images appear in the same 'column' as the text - responsive design.

Any ideas on how this could be achieved? Is it possible? I've spent a few hours playing around but am none the wiser!

Answer (score 2):

I would do something along the line of this:
http://jsfiddle.net/RjDaS/16/

I would wrap every paragraf tag in a div (this one has a class called section) and let the image be next to it. This will also work for your responsive design. However I was unable to let your image stay in the page_content div.

```
<div class="page_content">
    <p>A paragraph of text.</p>
    <div class="Section">
        <p>Another paragraph of text.</p>
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div >
    <p>Some more text.</p> 

</div>
```

​

css:

```
.Section p{

    float:left;
    /*min-width:24em;*/
    max-width:36em;
        margin-right:10px;
}
.Section img{
    float:left;
}
.Section{
    overflow:hidden;
}
​
​
```

Edit: Added float left so it will stay close to the p tag. (Removed min-width for better visualization)

Comment: Yep, that's along the lines I was thinking, thanks. The only issue still is that the image just budges right up against the right hand side of the page - I can't find a way to keep it just a few px/ems/whatever away from the right hand side of the paragraph which it is 'associated' with.

Comment: Even better! Is there a way to persuade the paragraphs below the image to move up and continue the flow of the text as if the image isn't there? I.e. at the moment there is a massive white vertical gap between the two paragraphs, sized to the image.

Comment: You mean, like having everything floating left or displaying the p tags inline? Not sure what you exactly want. this http://jsfiddle.net/RjDaS/36/ ? I'll answer the rest of your comments tomorrow if there are any more questions. Please accept the answer if you find it satisfying :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm so rubbish at explaining! I've made a quick mockup pic instead: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/93558837/p-img-eg.png - hopefully this gives a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: ah ha, you can give the image some margin left instead (and remove the margin from the p tag). Depending on it's width, and the width of the p tags you get what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/RjDaS/46/

Comment: Sorry for delay in getting back to you. I'm becoming convinced that what I want to do can't be done (at least, not without jQuery). - In the latest jsfiddle, the subsequent paras still can't push their way up to join the previous paragraphs. But thanks for your efforts!